# Keep UITableView offset when inserting rows at the top with UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have an `UITableView` with `Autolayout` in my app.
I need  insert some rows to my TableView after press `LoadEarlier` Button to index[0],
but i want to stay on my last position of my TableView.(Load Earlier Like WhatsApp & ...).

My problem is after setting `contentOffset` the posion  of my TableVoew isn't correct.

i check this link but this the problem isn't like my problem but i think the answer help us.
[UITableViewAutomaticDimension - Cells move when table is reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107130/uitableview-powered-by-fetchedresultscontroller-with-uitableviewautomaticdimensi/30126655#30126655)
and this link :
[Keep uitableview static when inserting rows at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279730/keep-uitableview-static-when-inserting-rows-at-the-top)

i do Like this :

```
// in ViewDidLoad
self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
self.myTableView.rowHeight  = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;


//implemention of LoadEalier Method
CGFloat oldTableViewHeight = self.myTableView.contentSize.height;

for (int i = temp ; i < temp +26; i++) {
    myObject * tempObject = [[myObject alloc]init];
    tempObject.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Obj : %d",i];
    tempObject.uID = [[NSUUID UUID]UUIDString];
    [_dataArray insertObject:tempObject atIndex:0];
}

[self.myTableView reloadData];
CGFloat newTableViewHeight = self.myTableView.contentSize.height;
self.myTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.myTableView.contentSize.height - oldTableViewHeight);
```

if i remove AutomaticDimension from my Delegate & .... it's work perfectly on static Height of  Cell ,but i need AutomaticDimension to calculate height of my cell.

Comment: Since you're setting your `tableView`'s `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` I think you can remove `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` methods.

Comment: yes but it's not causes this problem

Comment: Here on stack overflow there is a lot of problems with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `contentOffset` in vary contexts. It always makes a problems. Still not solved.

Comment: @Bartłomiej Semańczyk yes, i'm agree with you , but i have handled it by removing  `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from  HeightForRow & handle it by another way !

Comment: what way did you handle it?

Comment: check the answer :) maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

i can't find a solution for keep `UITableView` offset  with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

i have removed `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` & `estimateForRowAtIndexPath` and for keep `UITableView`  :

```
CGFloat oldTableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height; // we keep current content offSet for revert to this position after Reload Table

// Update your Data

[self.tableView reloadData];

CGFloat finalYPostioton = self.tableView.contentSize.height - oldTableViewHeight - numberOfYourSection * sectionHeight;

finalYPostioton = finalYPostioton - spaceFromTopCell; // we need this for showing a little of top cell from our index. spaceFromTopCell -->10

[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,finalYPostioton)  animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and effective trick:

```
var upsideDown: Bool = true

// swap table view vertically
tableView.transform = upsideDown
  ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
  : .identity

// swap cell in cellForRowAt method
cell.transform = upsideDown
  ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
  : .identity
```

Insert rows as usual, the rows will appear on the top of tableview.

This works fine with UITableView.automaticDimension and scrolling stays smooth.

The first rows will be stick to the bottom of tableview though but you can fix it with extra coding.